# How to Match Two input value if not equal alert message in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hello I have a table form that appends using jquery all i want is when entering a value in line and enter a second value in onther line must be an equal or alert message?

so when enter value in line one and enter onther value in line two alert message if not equal

code for controller

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];
    $head = TransactionHead::where('status',1)->pluck('tr_head','id')->toArray();
    $data['th'] =  array_prepend($head,'Select Ledger','0');

    $data['url'] = URL::current();
    $data['filter_query'] = $this->filter_query;

    return view(parent::loadDataToView($this->view_path.'.add'), compact('data'));
}

public function store(AddValidation $request)
{



    if($request->get('account_type') == "dr_amt"){
        $drAmount = $request->amount;
        $crAmount = 0;
    }elseif ($request->get('account_type') == "cr_amt"){
        $drAmount = 0;
        $crAmount = $request->amount;
    }else{

    }

    $data = [
        'date'          => $request->date,
        'tr_head_id' =>  $request->tr_head,
        'dr_amount' => $drAmount,
        'cr_amount' => $crAmount,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'created_by' => auth()->user()->id
    ];

    Transaction::create($data);

    $request->session()->flash($this->message_success, $this->panel. ' Add Successfully.');

    if($request->add_transaction_another) {
        $head = TransactionHead::where('status',1)->pluck('tr_head','id')->toArray();
        $data['th'] =  array_prepend($head,'Select Ledger','0');

        return back();
    }else{
        return redirect()->route($this->base_route);
    }

}
```

code for view

```
   <table id="sample-table-1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    {{--class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"--}}
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th width="30%">Ledger</th>
        <th width="30%">Description</th>
        <th>Dr. Amount</th>
        <th>Cr. Amount</th>
        <th>
            <span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="load-transaction-html">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="transaction_wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                    <span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" >
                        <i class="fa fa-arrows" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {!! Form::hidden('chkIds[]', 1, ["class" => "input-sm form-control border-form"]) !!}
            {!! Form::text('date[]', null, ["class" => "input-sm form-control border-form input-mask-date date-picker", "data-date-format" => "yyyy-mm-dd","required","autofocus"]) !!}
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="tr_head[]" class=" form-control" id="form-field-select-3" data-placeholder="Choose a Ledger/Transaction Head..." required>
                <option value="">  </option>
                @foreach( $data['th'] as $key => $th)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $th }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" id="description" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="dr_amount[]" id="dr_amount" min="0" placeholder="0"  autocomplete="off" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" name="cr_amount[]" id="cr_amount" min="0" placeholder="0"  autocomplete="off" required>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                    <span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash bigger-120" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

code for appending form

```
@section('js')
@include('includes.scripts.inputMask_script')
@include('includes.scripts.datepicker_script')
<!-- inline scripts related to this page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*Change Field Value on Capital Letter When Keyup*/
        $(function() {
            $('.upper').keyup(function() {
                this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
            });
        });
        /*end capital function*/

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#load-transaction-html').click(function () {
            insertNewRow();
        });



        $('#sample-table-1').on('click','tr:last',function(){
            copyLastRow();
        });

        $('#sample-table-1').on('focus','tr:last',function(e){
            //copyLastRow();

        });

        function copyLastRow(){
            var $tableBody = $('#sample-table-1').find("tbody"),
                $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
                $trNew = $trLast.clone();
            $trLast.after($trNew);

        }

        function insertNewRow(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('account.multi-transaction.tr-html') }}',
                data: {
                    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);

                    if (data.error) {
                        //$.notify(data.message, "warning");
                    } else {

                        $('#transaction_wrapper').append(data.html);
                        $(document).find('option[value="0"]').attr("value", "");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });

</script>
```

here image to explaine more
[image: this table form with input rows]

Comment: Please be more descriptive. Which field or fields are you talking about? What is line 1 and line 2? Can you give a description of the expected response? For example: _If user enters a value in the quantity field in one table row, then check to make sure they enter the same value in the quantity field of the next row_

Comment: i have table form in row 1 i enter a value in it and second row 2 appear also enter a value in it so the equation is row1.value = row2.value

Comment: ok, which field are we comparing? tr_head[], description[] .. or ?

Comment: It looks like your call to `.clone()` will clone the input fields `#dr_amount` and `#cr_amount`, resulting in multiple elements with the same ID. You'll want to change that so each input field has a unique ID.

Comment: Are you only trying to compare the first two rows? What if there are, say, five rows?

Comment: not two but all value must be the same  all i want when entering a value in row one must be equal to row 2 and the rest of rows that show under or alert message

Comment: Your question is still not clear . Please edit your question with more details .